# Topology, closed sets and interiors

Tags: general-topology

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}\newcommand{\int}{\operatorname{int}}$So there’s another excercise I’ve been struggling with recently, very similar to the previous one.

> Let $A$ be a subset of topological space $X$ and:
>
> $B:=X\setminus\cl\int A$.
>
> Prove that $B=\int\cl B$.

I’ve got the first part, that left side is included in the right side, what was pretty obvious. Harder part is proving second inclusion. Any ideas? Also, have you got any good excercises books or something like that, because I definetly need some training and in my book there aren’t much excercises.

Comment: Try to write your question using MathJax and more people will answer

Comment: Okey, I’ll try, but theres not much to write in MathJax. I could do like the straigh line above set instead writing Cl, but as I ve seen so far, everybody is using the notation Cl

Comment: \overline{A} $\overline{A}$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prob. 21, Sec. 17, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: Closure and complementation can result in at most 14 different sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1626025/prob-21-sec-17-in-munkres-topology-2nd-ed-closure-and-complementation-can)